# Shell Script - Ping and create folder from list of servers

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm trying to create a script to ping a list of servers, and it will write the result to a text file, then it will create a folder to the list of servers.

```
FILENAME="hosts"

while IFS='' read -r LINE || [[ -n "$LINE" ]]; do    
ping -c 3 $LINE >>/home/user/scripts/results.txt
sshpass -p 'P@ssword' ssh$LINE 'cd/home/user/Desktop;mkdir test'
echo
done < "/home/user/scripts/servers.txt"
```

The ping is working fine, but after i add the command to create a folder, it will only have the first server ping result, and create the folder on the first server.

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure `ssh$LINE` works at all?  Would `ssh10.10.10.1` work from the command line (assuming a valid IP)?

Comment: Yes, I just tested, and works fine after add -n

Comment: @Jesse_b No, that part should never have worked unless the addresses have spaces in front of them.

Comment: (1) You should always quote shell variables every time you use them unless you have a good reason not to and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  `$LINE` should be `"$LINE"` (every time). (2) You seem to have a problem with the space bar on your keyboard.  `ssh$LINE` should not have worked, and `cd/home/user/Desktop` is definitely wrong. (3) I don’t understand what you mean by “create a  folder to the list of servers”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` reads standard input. It inherits the standard input from the `while` loop.  This means it will gobble up all the remaining lines from your file.

This is easily solved by using `ssh -n` which redirects `/dev/null` into the standard input of `ssh`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r addr || [ -n "$addr" ]; do    
    ping -c 3 "$addr" 
    sshpass -p 'P@ssword' ssh -n "$addr" 'mkdir Desktop/test'
    echo
done < "$HOME/scripts/servers.txt" >"$HOME/scripts/results.txt"
```

Comment: It works!! Brilliant!!!!!!!!!!